# Redirecting a domain without hosting server

Tags: dns, web-hosting

I have a website, lets call it "olddomain.com".
I bought new domain, lets call it "newdomain.com"
What I want to do is to make newdomain.com redirect to olddomain.com/subdir without hosting newdomain.com on a new web hosting server. Is this doable?

Answer (score 0):

You Can do this with the help of domain control panel. There is option of domain forwarding through domain control panel. Need not to buy hosting.

```
using domain forwarding option in domain control pabel you can redirect your newdomain.com to olddomain.com/subdir
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to put a file inside of newdomain.com called by:

index.php

```
<?php 
header("Location: http://olddomain.com/subdir");
exit(0);
?>
```

or

index.asp

```
<%
Response.Redirect("http://olddomain.com/subdir")
%>
```

Comment: This would mean, that I have to put the file on a web hosting server, right? My point was not to do that. Or is there other ways I can "put a file inside of a domain" ?

Comment: You can set the DNS of newdomain.com as the same of olddomain.com (eg.: 123.456.789.000). This will redirect your users to olddomain.com. After that, you should set an alias/website at the server of olddomain.com to a new folder with the files that I commented above. Are you using IIS or Apache in olddomain.com?

Comment: Thanks. How do I set an alias / website at the server of olddomain.com?
I think that I am using Apache, but I am not fully sure about it. Does that change anything?

Comment: Yes, it change everythig if you're using Apache or IIS. These links (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-configurar-apache-virtual-hosts-no-ubuntu-14-04-lts-pt in portuguese and https://www.debian-administration.org/article/412/Hosting_multiple_websites_with_Apache2 in english) shows the step by step to configure your websites.